# Retrieving Exchange 2010 Conference Room Calendar Statistics using PowerShell?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I need to gather statistics on the usage of our 7 conference rooms at my office (each of which is a Room resource mailbox in Exchange), and I'm hoping I can use PowerShell to do this. I am running Exchange 2010 (SP2 Rollup 6, if it matters).

I would like to determine:

- How many meetings per day are booked in each of our conference rooms
- How many hours per day each room is booked (during business hours M-F 8am-5pm)

Is it possible to gather this information using PowerShell (using EMS) in Exchange 2010? If so, what Cmdlets should I start with? I've taken a quick look at `Get-MailboxStatistics` and `Get-MailboxCalendarFolder`, but I'm not sure either will get me the information I need. I'm familiar with getting ItemSize, NumberOfItems, etc with Get-MailboxStatistics on mailboxes but that does not deal with calendar entries.

I've also done

```
Get-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity room-mailbox:\Calendar | Get-Member
```

...and the available methods don't look very interesting.

If this isn't possible, are there any alternatives available besides manually looking at calendar free/busy information? This is a one time thing, so if it's not possible it won't be a major loss.

Comment: Have you researched exactly which Exchange API's provide the data your looking for?  If there isn't a specific CMDLET for it you may be able to leverage invoking the .NET code from powershell to access the API in question

Comment: @organicit No, I haven't. That is a good idea but given it's a one off I think I will probably just load up the calendars to get this information.

Comment: shall we continue this thread to try to identify what you would have needed or shall we close this out?